# HasFlag with a generic enum?

Tags: c#, generics, enums, enum-flags

I am just starting with `Generics` in C# but have run into a problem early on, how can I call `.HasFlag()` on a generic `Enum`?

```
public class Example<TEnum> where TEnum : struct {
}
```

How can I add the `[Flags]` attribute to it?

Comment: In short, you can't. Constraints do not consider attributes on the generic parameters. You'd have to enforce it through reflection.

Comment: Type parameters are supposed to start with `T`; you should change `GenericEnum` to `TEnum`.

Comment: could you give an example @M.Babcock? and duly noted, @SLaks

Comment: Also you can use [John Skeet's library](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/09/11/1722426.aspx) to enforce enum constraint if you like.

Comment: @AnuragRanjhan the library link above returns a 404 error. Could you please update?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling the instance method will require boxing anyway, so, since you can't constrain to `Enum`, just abandon generics and use `Enum`.  For example, instead of:

```
void Something(TEnum enumValue, TEnum flags)
{
    if (enumValue.HasFlags(flags))
        //do something ...
}
```

Do this:

```
void Something(Enum enumValue, Enum flags)
{
    if (enumValue.HasFlags(flags))
        //do something ...
}
```

In a generic method, you could achieve your goal like this:

```
void Something(TEnum enumValue, TEnum flags)
{
    Enum castValue = (Enum)(object)enumValue;
    Enum castFlags = (Enum)(object)flags;

    if (castValue.HasFlags(castFlags))
        //do something ...
}
```

This will throw an exception at runtime if you call the method with a value type that isn't an enum.  You could also cast via `ValueType` rather than `object`, since the type parameter is known to represent a value type:

```
Enum castValue = (Enum)(ValueType)enumValue;
```

Comment: I was doing what you were suggesting initially, but am trying to refactor several methods that use your example into one that will take a generic enum and still be able to call has flags on it

Comment: @Tyler I added an example showing how you can cast an instance of a generic type parameter to `Enum`.

Comment: thanks @phoog. am still trying to work it out but have noticed that the HasFlag() method has appeared in intellisense!

Comment: @Tyler you're welcome.  Also note that the `HasFlags` method will work even if your type argument is an enum that doesn't have the `Flags` attribute.  If you want to prevent calling HasFlags on a non-flags enum, you'll need to do a runtime check using reflection.  If you perform that check in the static constructor of your class, it will have virtually no impact on performance.