# c# Bit operators '&' and 'Enum.HasFlag' Difference

Tags: c#, enums, bit

```
enum Type{
   Monster = 1 << 0,
   Human = 1 << 1,
   Boss = 1 << 2,
}

Type unit = Type.Mosnter | Type.Boss;

Type eSearch = Type.Monster | Type.Human | Type.Boss;

Debug.Log((eSearch & unit) != 0);  // True
Debug.Log(eSearch.HasFlag(unit))   // True

eSearch = Type.Monster | Type.Human;

Debug.Log((eSearch & unit) != 0);  // True
Debug.Log(eSearch.HasFlag(unit))   // False
```

I want to know in detail why the first and second result values are different when using the above code.

HasFlag seems to make a perfect comparison, so please tell me what bit operations (such as '&') are internal actions.

Ps. I understand the first and second '&' operations.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Your comparison is wrong: should be `(eSearch & unit) != unit` which correctly returns false. `!= 0` semantically means: are *any* of the bits in `unit` present in `eSearch`, whereas you want: are *all* the bits present

Comment: eSearch.HasFlag(unit) equals to eSearch & unit == unit

Comment: Thank you, everyone.  I understand! Have a nice day today :-)

Comment: The version using the bitwise AND operator may be preferrable, because `HasFlag` requires boxing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665279/why-enums-hasflag-method-need-boxing

Comment: @KlausGütter That's a good point. So i want use bit operator, but i have no idea.... If you don't mind, could you look at my new question? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69039700/c-sharp-flagenum-generic-usage?noredirect=1#comment122017919_69039700

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `HasFlag` seems to make a perfect comparison

Yes. It checks if the enum value has *all* of the values present in the argument. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.hasflag?view=net-5.0#remarks), the bit operation performed is:

```
thisInstance And flag = flag
```

In other words, `eSearch.HasFlag(unit)` is the same as:

```
(eSearch & unit) == unit
```

It's checking whether the AND is exactly the same as `unit`, not just non-zero.

Side note: you should also add the [`[Flags]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=net-5.0#remarks) attribute to your `Type` enum:

```
[Flags]
enum Type {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Oh, well, let me get this is...

1. Complete comparison of all desired bits on: (eSearch & unit) == unit
2. Some comparisons to check that any bit is On: (eSearch & unit) != 0

Is this right?